# List dependencies that do not have wheel

Tags: python, pip, python-poetry

I am on a project where some libraries are pretty old, and I won't upgrade them in order to avoid recompiling with a C/C++ compiler

Is there some way to verify or check which dependencies there is no pre-built wheel?

Let me explain better: I have a project with some outdated libraries, those libraries have binaries for amd64, but not for arm64. I am looking for a way to list those libraries and upgrade only these libraries (hopefully now they have binaries for arm64)

Comment: You mean no pre-built wheel for your old installed version or no pre-built wheel for a potential version after an upgrade?

Comment: Let me explain better: I have a project with some outdated libraries, those libraries have binaries for amd64, but not for arm64. I am looking for a way to list those libraries and upgrade only these libraries (hopefully now they have binaries for arm64)

Comment: I'm a little confused by what I think are two different uses of "have binaries". Am I correct in thinking you want to select only packages that (1) are currently only installed for amd64, and (2) have binaries available (to install) for arm64?

Comment: I understand. Let me explain. I got a new brand MacBook m1, and I am working on a project that has some libraries dated in 2019 that are native (C or C++ code) which do not have an arm64 version published, only the new versions, however, I can not do a full upgrade of all libraries, I want to pick each by each and test an upgrade, but first, I want to know if it is possible to list all libraries that does not have native package for arm64 OR is a native library (that is need to be compiled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could attempt to run

```
pip install --only-binary=:all:  -r requirements.txt
```

in the target platform and see what versions get resolved or what fails with a "No matching distribution found".

Beware that if you run into a pure python project that didn't publish a wheel yet, you should exempt it with the `--no-binary` flag.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing with poetry?